# Performance of Arrays.asList

Tags: java, performance, optimization

What is the cost of using Arrays.asList to convert static object arrays? Assuming that the object array has N items is it just an O(N) algorithm, where all of the items are copied by reference or is it merely a facade where the original array is put behind a List facade?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It is cheap, O(1). As you suspect the list is merely a wrapper around the array. This is confirmed by the [Java API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29):

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.)

Comment: When going the other direction (Collection.toArray) the array is not "write-through".  Changes to the array won't affect the list the array came from.

Comment: In otherwords sam, it clones the original array.