# Best way to initialise a list with just one element without splitting the declaration and initialisation

Tags: java

I found this line in the code

```
 List<Element> elements = Arrays.asList(element);
```

and found it weird that we need to use Arrays.asList() on just one element. That got me thinking if there is a better way to initialise an ArrayList with just one element without making it immutable. 
As far as I have read, there is no constructor for ArrayList which takes just one element.

**EDIT- As per Aomine's answer, I have found this to be the only way at this point to do what I needed**

```
List<Element> elements = Stream.of(element).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performance of Arrays.asList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552783/performance-of-arrays-aslist)

Comment: Or if you use kotlin: `val elements = mutableListOf(element)` :-)

Comment: Note that `Arrays.asList` doesn't give you a fully mutable `List`. It returns a fixed size `List`, which means that you can use `set` method on it, but using `add` or `remove` will throw `UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: Libraries like _Eclipse Collections_ or _Guava_ contain better helper methods to create mutable lists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best you can do *under the current version of Java* is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

...
//additional elements can be added (later) to all lists -> all are immutable (also to the 2nd!)

List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(element));
// or
List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(element));
// or
List<Element> elements = Stream.of(element)
                               .collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: I can't find the toCollection method. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Napstablook sorry, forgot to mention.  you need the `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;`

Comment: Oh right and this  is great. the last one is the  one I was looking for.

Comment: @Napstablook May I ask why you opt for that solution? I don't want to be rude but in terms of performance it's terrible considering the alternatives.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle - I understand that. I selected it as it is the only way to actually make a list with one element without making it immutable. I am open for any other method.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle you're not rude at all. that's a fair point to make. although, "terrible" doesn't seem like the right word, maybe "sub-optimal" is better. nevertheless,  it's only _one_ element and not _really huge_ numbers so one wouldn't even notice the performance. :)

Comment: @Napstablook well no! All these three approaches produce a mutable collection!

Comment: Oh, But as per what I read in the documentation, Collections.singletonList() creates an immutable list. Correct me if I am wrong.
PS- Yes, Just checked, It throws a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException when you try to add another element to the list.

Comment: True, but you pass it to the constructor of `ArrayList` that only uses this collection to create a new mutable List. (Also, Stream example can be shortened: `Stream.of(element).collect(Collectors.toList())`.)

Comment: @NicoVanBelle **be very careful with that** as per the java doc [toList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) --> "**There are no guarantees** on the type, **mutability**, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned; if more control over the returned List is required, use toCollection(Supplier).", So, although currently `toList` returns a _mutable_ list, it's not guaranteed to always remain that way.

Comment: @Aominè Good catch. Learned something myself today.